# Can I reset cursor's position to the beginning?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

As in the topic. Can I simply reset cursor's position to the beginning in Transact-SQL, so it can run again over the table? I want to reset it in the following context:

```
DECLARE @userID INT
DECLARE user_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT userID FROM users

WHILE /* some condition */
BEGIN
...

    FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor INTO @userID

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        /*... here goes the reset of the cursor ...*/
    END

...
END
```

Comment: Refer below link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909357/start-position-for-a-reused-t-sql-cursor

Answer (score 41, accepted):

you need to declare your cursor as scroll, like this

```
declare c scroll cursor for (select statement);
```

then at any time for locating to the first just use the following

```
fetch first from c;
```

Comment: for preventing of changes(update/delete) you would declare the cursor READ_ONLY just after the scroll

Comment: Also you need to Declare your cursor as `DECLARE @CursorX SCROLL CURSOR SELECT ...` or `SET @CursorX = CURSOR SCROLL FOR SELECT ....`

Answer (score 24):

Another option that can be used that doesn't force you to change the type of cursor is simply to [close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175035.aspx) the cursor and re-[open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190500.aspx) it:

```
CLOSE user_cursor
OPEN user_cursor
```

But the [`scroll` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17318016/15498) will be cheaper in terms of resource usage, if that's a change you can accept.

Comment: Do You know which method is faster?

Comment: @OskarSzura - as I said, the scroll should be cheaper (at the point at which you issue the `fetch first`). On the other hand, it may be more expensive during the initial `open`. But the only way to really know would be to try out both with *your* data, *your* indexes, *your* hardware, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The data retrieved by the cursor will not change.

STATIC

Defines a cursor that makes a temporary copy of the data to be used by the cursor. All requests to the cursor are answered from this temporary table in tempdb; therefore, modifications made to base tables are not reflected in the data returned by fetches made to this cursor, and this cursor does not allow modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a similar answer in PostgreSQL.

`MOVE FIRST` goes to the end of the first row, i.e. running `FETCH ALL` after this will return all rows apart from first one.
There doesn't seem to be a `MOVE ZEROTH` option. So this works:

```
MOVE FIRST c;
MOVE PRIOR c;
FETCH ALL c;
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -5):

Use cursor loops and its taken care of for you...

```
cursor c_something IS
   select * from somewhere

BEGIN

    for some_row in c_something LOOP
        -- do stuff with some_row.COLUMN;
    END LOOP; -- this closes the cursor for you when it has gone all the way through

    -- do other stuff

    for some_row in c_something LOOP -- opens the cursor again from the top
        -- do stuff with some_row.COLUMN;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: The question is SQL Server/Sybase TSQL not Oracle, right?