# How to reuse a cursor in tsql from the begining

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to reuse a cursor in tsql from the beginning without changing its definition.

I saw this topic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317732/can-i-reset-cursors-position-to-the-begining) but I dont know what to do after this

```
 fetch first from c;
```

I used after this code :

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

        BEGIN 

        ...
            FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @myVariable;
        END;

        CLOSE c;    
        DEALLOCATE c;
```

but it didnt work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I reset cursor's position to the begining?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317732/can-i-reset-cursors-position-to-the-begining)

Comment: I saw that topic but I didnt get my answer because the answer didnt work for me and dont know what to do after     fetch first from c;  to reuse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a scroll cursor with read only and reset to the first record from the cursor when needed.

For example:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Id int, Num int);
insert into @T values (1,0),(2,0),(3,0);

DECLARE @ID INT;
DECLARE @Num INT;
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0;
DECLARE c SCROLL CURSOR FOR (SELECT Id, Num FROM @T) FOR READ ONLY;

OPEN c;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ID, @Num;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @Counter <= 3
BEGIN

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
    UPDATE @T SET num = @Counter WHERE Id = @ID;

    IF @ID = 2
        BEGIN FETCH FIRST FROM c INTO @ID, @Num; END;
    ELSE 
        BEGIN FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ID, @Num; END;

END;

CLOSE c;

select * from @T;
```

Gets:

```
Id  Num
1   3
2   4
3   0
```

Just be aware that the values you get from the cursor don't change.
Since there's only 1 open and close.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN 
        DROP TABLE #tmp;
    END;

CREATE TABLE #tmp (num INT IDENTITY(10,10))

-- **** execute separately ****
INSERT INTO #tmp DEFAULT VALUES
GO 10
-- ****************************
DECLARE c scroll cursor for select num FROM #tmp;
OPEN c;
DECLARE @i int = 1,
        @cursor_value INT;

 WHILE @i < 10
BEGIN

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @i = 5 
    BEGIN
        FETCH FIRST FROM c INTO @cursor_value;
    END
    ELSE 
        FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @cursor_value

    SELECT @i AS cntr, @cursor_value AS crsr

    SET @i +=1
END

close c
DEALLOCATE c
```